# Updating an item of a ListView for some action done

Tags: android, listview

I searched for this, and tried many things, and for sometime it seemed solved, but it wasn't

This is my application behaviour:

**1. ListView with 1st 10 items fetched from a web server in an AsyncTask, and stored in an ArrayList.**

**2. Set this ArrayList to the Adapter**

**3. onScroll, if reached last item, fetch 10 more items, add to the ArrayList and so on**

*Problem:*

There is a button on every item to thank , which has an initial count took from the data of that particular item, from the ArrayList.

let it be **10**

Since this is an action item, i had a **onClickListener** for this button in the **getView()** in the Adapter.

```
onClick(){

//change the count to count+1 or change 10 to 11
}
```

this works but when i scroll the List, this count is set back to **count (10)** instead of retaining **count + 1 (11)**. This is because the item is being recreated, and the data being used to get count is from the ArrayList, which is old 1 (10). To make this work i need to update the data in the server, get it back and store in the ArrayList and use it to get **count + 1 (11)**.

Is there a way to do this. Because i cant call the server to give me new data every time an action item is clicked. Because this will be something like ListView is recreated, losing all the scrolled items.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by focused you mean selected (scrolled down by the keyboard, has the selection rectangle around it) then just use `setOnItemSelectedListener`. The int argument is the position, compare that to the number of items in your list and you're golden.

If by focused you mean visible, then use `setOnScrollListener`, which has this method:

```
onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
```

Just first + visible will get the last item shown, which you can compare to the total. then write update the adapter with remaining items...

Comment: Its an action item on the List Item, so i cannot just implement setOnItemSelectedListener. I must use setOnClickListener in the getView() if the adapter.

Comment: try to understand this code may be this is usefull for you http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/listview-with-checkboxes-without-listactivity.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load more data on scroll then try this

first implement `OnScrollListener`

and implement override

```
@Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view,
            int firstVisible, int visibleCount, int totalCount) {

        boolean loadMore = firstVisible + visibleCount >= totalCount;

            if(loadMore) {
                Remainingdata=totaldata-(firstVisible + visibleCount);
                System.out.println(totaldata);
                System.out.println(visibleCount);
                System.out.println(Remainingdata);
                if(Remainingdata<visibleCount){
                    yourlist.count += Remainingdata; // or any other amount
                }else{
                    yourlist.count += visibleCount; // or any other amount
                }
                yourlist.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
    }


    @Override
     public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView v, int s) { }
```

Comment: Its not about loading. Its about updating the UI of an Item using its data from the ArrayAdapter

Comment: @Archie.bpgc yes if you have data in your list then this will display limited data first and on scroll remaining data get visible.